# Referencing PHP constants in Smarty template

Tags: smarty

I am very much a newbie to this topic.  I have an application that uses Smarty templates.  In one of the HTML files I want to be able to pull out the filename portion of a file path stored in a Smarty variable, and do it using a PHP function as a modifier via pipe:

```
{$file|pathinfo:PATHINFO_FILENAME}
```

Of course this doesn't work.  When I substitute a literal instead, it works as expected:

```
{$file|pathinfo:2}
```

So if the Smarty variable $file contains the string "images/products/foo.png", I get "foo.png" which is what I wanted.  My question:  Is there a better way?

Comment: The first line should work this way: `{$file|pathinfo:$smarty.const.PATHINFO_FILENAME}`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the php file, try using `extends`:

```
$smarty->display("extends:PATHINFO_FILENAME|CURRENT_TPL_FILE");
```

Comment: thanks, I don't have access to the source code.  All I have are the .html files to work with.